# How to use if/else statement to act on Get-ADUser lockout property

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script with powershell and combine it with XAML to make some Active Directory management tasks easier for myself. I'm currently hung up on trying to query whether accounts are locked or not.

```
#Making the Check Account Button display the Lockout property
$WPFCheck_Account.Add_Click({
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $WPFInput_User.Text} -Properties LockedOut | Select-Object LockedOut
    if($User -eq $null)
        {$WPFCheck_Results.AddChild("Account Not Found")}
    elseif($User = "True")
        {$WPFCheck_Results.AddChild("Account Locked Out")}
    elseif($User = "False")
        {$WPFCheck_Results.AddChild("Account Not Locked Out")}         
})
```

The first `if` statement successfully filters invalid account names, but all valid account names are caught by the second `if` and labeled as locked out. I originally thought the problem was with my `$status` variable and the comparison with the "true" or "false" strings, but in my searches I found others using the same strings so I'm not sure where my problem is.

Comment: Why call `Get-ADUser` twice?

Comment: Because if I only have one of them, all queries are caught by the first `if` and marked "Account Not Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to variable, not comparing them, (old equal-sign pit we have all fallen to) so the second `if` always gets `$true`. Also, `LockedOut` property is `Boolean`, not `String`, so it can only have two values after you have checked out `$null`. No need for the third `if`:

```
elseif($User)
        {$WPFCheck_Results.AddChild("Account Locked Out")}
    else
        {$WPFCheck_Results.AddChild("Account Not Locked Out")}
```

Comment: Janne, hit post before I did. 8^}   --- and much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

How about either of these two approaches. Well, you have to tweak for your form, but you know...

```
($UserName = $env:USERNAME)

Administrator

If (-Not (Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $Username} -Properties sAMAccountName,LockedOut))
{Write-Warning -Message "The user $UserName was not found"}
ElseIf(Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username} -Properties sAMAccountName,LockedOut)
{"$UserName account is not locked out"}
Else{Write-Warning -Message "$UserName account is locked out"}

Administrator account is not locked out


$AccountStatus = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $Username} -Properties sAMAccountName,LockedOut
switch ($AccountStatus.LockedOut) 
    { 
        'False' {"$UserName account is not locked out"} 
        'True ' {Write-Warning -Message "$UserName account is locked out"} 
        default {Write-Warning -Message "The user $UserName was not found"}
    }

Administrator account is not locked out
```